# Confusion on Provisioning Profile in APNS?

Tags: iphone

I want to activate APNs on to my application, and my application already have Provisioning profile but push notification is not active yet, now what i need is just to configure profile and activate push notification or should i create another provision profile with activate Push notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to configure the app ID( of the profile being used ),to enable push notifications. See the APP ID section of the provisioning portal.

Comment: do you've tutorial link for activate APNS?

Comment: Go to APP IDs section of the provisioning portal. Click on the "How To" tab on the top. There is a section called "Registering an App ID for Apple Push Notification service".